# Read contents of a file during boot in an upper volume filter driver

Tags: c, windows, filter, driver, volume

I am working on an upper volume filter driver based on diskperf.
My driver actually monitors the sectors that are modified and sets the respective blocks in a bitmap. When the system is properly shutdown, the bitmap buffer is copied into a bitmap file.

So now what my requirement is, when the system restarts, I need to copy the contents of this bitmap file into our bitmap buffer before any "Writes" occur to any partition.

So, can anyone tell me how can I achieve this?
Also which function or IOCTL can be used to detect when the partition is actually mounted during boot?

I tried to use `IOCTL_DISK_IS_WRITABLE` IOCTL, after detecting it I am opening the bitmap file using `ZwOpenFile/ZwCreateFile` to read contents from it, but the system hangs over here and does not move on. I am not getting any error in `Windbg` also. What can be the possible cause?

Note: The file is present in the desired location("\Device\Harddisk1\Partition1\file.txt"), when trying to open it.

Awaiting a positive response.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Assuming that the partition containing the file is one of those you are monitoring, there's probably no way to read the file before any writes occur to the partition.  You'll need to keep track of any writes that happen during the boot process, and merge the contents of the file later.  If you're blocking completion of IOCTL_DISK_IS_WRITABLE waiting for the read to complete you're probably causing a deadlock.  I don't know how to tell that the partition is mounted, hopefully someone can answer this.

Comment: Mounting is file system related operation not volume level, so I don't think there is any notification for that for volume filters. Reading a file while mounting the same volume is deadlock. May be you can store bitmap file block locations at fixed blocks.

Comment: Hi, Thanks @HarryJohnston and @Rohan for your replies. If I store the bitmap file block locations in registry or at any other place than too I have to obtain a handle to the volume to read from that block location, so again I need to know when the partition is mounted to successfully obtain the handle. If the partition is not mounted I always gets an error while obtaining a handle using `ZwOpenFile/ZwCreateFile`. So what can be done to successfully obtain a handle before the partition is mounted?

Comment: Surely you can issue an IRP_MJ_READ to the volume device object in order to read blocks from the volume?